# Casting custom types

Tags: c#

I'm working on a custom struct and I would like to give it the ability to implicitly be created from another type.

Say I have two struct types. Color and ColorX, where Color is a struct already in the framework that I cannot change.

Using implicit operator, to be able to say for example.

```
Color C;
ColorX CX;
CX = new ColorX();
C = CX;
```

However, I would like to be able to do it the other way around as well. Either by directly setting it, or by making a cast. Being able to do both would be gold. For example.

```
C = new Color();
CX = C;
```

or cast it like so:

```
CX = (ColorX)C;
```

Consider all the other useful operators in C#, I'm sure there is a way to do this, I just can't find the syntax.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do this with the [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in C#:

```
public static implicit operator ColorX(Color original)
{
     return new ColorX(original);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast two unrelated types to each other.

I would create an extension med

```
public static class ColorExtensions 
{
   public static ColorX AsColorX(this Color c)
   {
       return new ColorC(c);
   }
}
```

to be able to invoke

```
Color c = new Color();
ColorX cx = c.AsColorX();
```